# Incorrect SecurityContext after Camel redirect

Tags: spring-security, apache-camel

I am using Spring Security 3.0.5 and Camel 1.5 (yes, very old but we don't have time to update right now).

In this particular scenario I am uploading a file which hits a Spring Controller which then redirects the request body (which is XML) to an endpoint which is a method in another class. Here is the issue: I had a tester perform an upload but when the GUI listing of files came back it had another person's name as the person who uploaded the file. During debugging I found that in the first Spring Controller the SecurityContext is correct in that it is indeed the credentials for the person performing the upload. After the Camel redirect though the SecurityContext was for another user who happened to have a session in the web app. Obviously this is not good.

So two questions:

1. Does anybody know what to do or if there is anything I can do using Camel 1.5 to fix this issue?
2. Why would the credentials of another user from another session be in this session? This question is regardless of Camel.

Answer (score 0):

What http are you using? Can you check if there is a single thread only processing the request at all time, or is multiple threads involved?

And btw Camel 1.5 is EOL, and not support at all anymore.

Comment: Using https.Just did a test and the Spring Controller is running in a different thread from where the Camel endpoint is running.